# Wrong data reception using HAL_SPI_Receive

Tags: stm32, spi, hal

I am trying to stablish a simple communication between two STM32 boards using SPI (NUCLEO-F401RE board as full duplex master and NUCLE0-L152RE board as full duplex slave). I have not been able to achieve it yet. Here is my code:

TX

```
uint8_t txdata[4] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04};

int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();

  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_SPI2_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();

  printf("STM32F401RE - Master TX\r\n");

  while (1)
  {
      HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi2, txdata, 4, 100);
      HAL_Delay(200);
  }
}
```

RX

```
uint8_t rxdata[4] = {0x00};

int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();

  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_SPI2_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();

  printf("STM32L152RE - Master RX\r\n");

  while (1)
  {
      HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi2, rxdata, 4, 1000);
      for(int i=0;i<sizeof(rxdata);i++)
      {
          printf("%X", rxdata[i]);
      }
      printf("\r\n");
      HAL_Delay(1000);
  }
}
```

And here is what I receive:

```
STM32L152RE - Master RX
1413
1141
4141
4131
4131
4131
3131
4141
4141
3141
3141
4141
4131
4131
4141
3141
3141
4141
4141
4141
4131
3141
3131
4131
3131
4131
...
```

I would expect rxdata to be 1234 (0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04) but as you can see, data is shifted and I dont even see the byte 0x02. What it could possibly be?

Comment: First you should do something like  `printf("0x%x ", rxdata[i]);` since your code output is not very readable.

Comment: Then you didn't show how you configured the SPIs.

Comment: Finally, how do you synchronise both boards ? The master must be launched only after the slave is ready to receive.

Comment: You don't need to add a delay between reception phases on slave side. AFAIR the HAL receive function is blocking at slave side.